# Mystical SQL binary operator =: in Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Littered throughout Magento you can find constructs similar to

```
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('c' => $couponTable),
            'c.customer_id=root.entity_id AND c.rule_id=:rule_id',
            array('c.coupon_id')
        );
```

What does the binary operator **=:** do?

Comment: its not the binary operator its the mysql variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of a prepare statement.  Take a look at [PDO's prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

So somewhere else it's binding a value to that variable... something like

```
$select->execute(array(":rule_id" => "someValue"));
```

Answer (score 5):

`=:` is not an operator. The operator is `=` only, which checks for equality. `:rule_id` is an identifier, which is used by prepared SQL statements to refer to a parameter. See prepared statements for more information.